# Id of selected item from autocomplete when pressing enter

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, knockout.js, keypress

I have an jquery autocomplete and which select membername with their id. I am getting the selected member id when select event is called like below:

```
//For autocomplete extender generating members
    $(function () {
            $('.tags').autocomplete({
                //make ajax call to get all members
                source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                                self.memberOptions(data.d);
                        });
                    }
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                        self.selectedMemberId(ui.item.value); //selected memberid
                }
            })
            .keypress(function (e, data, ui) {
                 if (e.which == 13) {
        //selected memberid when pressing enter key
        //self.selectedMemberId(ui.item.value); //selected memberid
             }
            });
    });
```

As in select event i am getting id of member, i want to get memberId in keypress event of autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tags').keypress(function (e) 
{
   e.preventDefault();
   var memberId = $(e.target).val();
});
```